# Why is the line 12 is printed twice?

Tags: c, arrays, runtime-error, binary-search

**Given Problem**

Implement the binary search algorithm in a non-recursive manner.
Keep the search array as a numeric array, initialized at time of declaration and keep it global.
The program should ask for a value to search, and then tell the location where it is found.
If the value is not found the program should display not found.
* Additionally the program should display the total number of comparisons done to locate the value ( or realize that the value was not found)

**My Solution**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int arr[]={1,3,4,6,8,9,10,15,17,21};
int bi_search(int n)
{
    int start=0,end=9,mid=0,count=0;
    while(start<=end)
    {
        count++;
        mid=(start+end)/2;
        if(n==arr[mid])
            {
                printf("\nThe total number of comparisons done to locate the value--%d\n",count);
                return mid;
            }
        else if(n<arr[mid])
            end=mid-1;
        else
            start=mid+1;
    }
    printf("\nThe total number of comparisons done to realize that the value was not found--%d\n",count);
    return-1;
}
main()
{
    int n=0,ch=0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value you want to search for--\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(bi_search(n)==-1)
             printf("\nSORRY :( !! \nThe value was not found.");
        else
             printf("\nHurray :) !! \nThe value you entered found at %d position", bi_search(n)+1);
        printf("\nEnter:-\n\t1 to continue.\n\t2 to terminate.\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
    }while(ch==1);
    printf("\nThank You\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, in function **bi_search(int n)** whenever **arr[mid]** becomes equal to **n**, line **The total number of comparisons done to locate the value--** is getting printed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `bi_search` function twice. Once in your `if` statement, and again in a `printf` statement. You should call it only once, and cache the value.

```
main()
{
    int n=0,ch=0;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value you want to search for--\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(bi_search(n)==-1) // Calling it here
             printf("\nSORRY :( !! \nThe value was not found.");
        else
             printf("\nHurray :) !! \nThe value you entered found at %d position", bi_search(n)+1); // And here
        printf("\nEnter:-\n\t1 to continue.\n\t2 to terminate.\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
    }while(ch==1);
    printf("\nThank You\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just because you are calling binary search function twice.
One on if part and other on else if part.

Alternatively you can do the same in following way

```
int temp = bi_search(n);
if (temp == -1)
    printf("Value not found\n");
else
    printf("Value found at position %d\n", temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main routine can look like this:

```
int main()
{
   int n = 0, ch = 0;
   do
   {
      printf("\nEnter the value you want to search for--\n");
      scanf("%d", &n);
      int res = bi_search(n); // store the result
      if (res == -1) // check if not find
         printf("\nSORRY :( !! \nThe value was not found.");
      else
         printf("\nHurray :) !! \nThe value you entered found at %d position", res + 1); // print if find
      printf("\nEnter:-\n\t1 to continue.\n\t2 to terminate.\n");
      scanf("%d", &ch);
   } while (ch == 1);
   printf("\nThank You\n");
   return 0;
}
```

1) int main() (to make compiler calm)

2) int res = bi_search(n) (to avoid second bi_search() call)